# BaseHash 'str' object has no attribute 'base'

Tags: python, authentication, hash

I want to add a login system with encryption, Expected: hash the login and do something with it (WIP), results: object has no attribute 'base' I tried encoding rather than hashing, Here is the code that you will need to reproduce the problem

```py
from basehash import base36
email = input("Login")
fnhash = base36.encode(email, 10)
print(fnhash)
```

Comment: I guess you''re using [this library](http://bnlucas.github.io/python-basehash/). It only accepts numbers instead of strings. Python provides the hashlib module for general purpose hashing. There are quite a few libraries for encryption. The above library does none of that. Keep in mind that passwords must be hashed often so that the whole operation is slow: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523.

Comment: @ArtjomB, numbers don't work either way.